# Picture position dependant of the selected option in a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can I dynamically position pictures depending on the selected option in a dropdown menu?

For example, if picture 1 is selected from dropdown 1, whatever picture I select from the next dropdown will inherit padding-top accordingly to the selected picture, let say, 20px.

I want to make that everything depends (dropdown 1 > dropdown 2 > dropdown 3), so the left dropdown put position conditions to the right dropdowns.
For example, if picture 4 from dropdown 2 is selected, anything I select from dropdown 3 will have 50px padding-left, but if I select picture 5 from dropdown 2, anything from dropdown 3 will have coordinates 60px padding-left.

Selected pictures from dropdowns should be loaded (changed) automatically on dropdown select, and also set a new rule for other dropdowns.

If picture 1 from dropdown 1 is selected it will show picture 1 in the blue div as is shown on the example picture and also will set a rule for every picture I choose from dropdown 2 to have padding-top: 20px

If I select picture 2 from dropdown 1 it will show picture 1 and also will set a rule for every picture from dropdown 2 to have padding-top: 30px

If I select a picture from dropdown 2 every picture from dropdown 3 will have inherited the position from dropdown 2, and so on...

I'm not sure if I explained it well but thanks for any suggestion you have.

[example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqGW4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Example how you can catch the currently values on a change event. So you can change the paddings of your images depending on the DropDownValues inside the event function.

```js
const dropDown1 = document.getElementById('dropDown1');
const dropDown2 = document.getElementById('dropDown2');
const dropDown3 = document.getElementById('dropDown3');
function changeDrop(){
  console.log(dropDown1.value);
  console.log(dropDown2.value);
  console.log(dropDown3.value);
  // Select your Images and define the paddings
}
```

```html
<label for="dropDown1">Drop 1:</label>
<select name="dropDown1" id="dropDown1" onchange="changeDrop()">
  <option value="pic1">Pic 1</option>
  <option value="pic2">Pic 2</option>
  <option value="pic3">Pic 3</option>
</select>

<label for="dropDown2">Drop 2:</label>
<select name="dropDown2" id="dropDown2" onchange="changeDrop()">
  <option value="pic4">Pic 4</option>
  <option value="pic5">Pic 5</option>
  <option value="pic6">Pic 6</option>
</select>

<label for="dropDown3">Drop 3:</label>
<select name="dropDown3" id="dropDown3" onchange="changeDrop()">
  <option value="pic7">Pic 7</option>
  <option value="pic8">Pic 8</option>
  <option value="pic9">Pic 9</option>
</select>
```